# Handling duplicate records in PIG Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

If there are duplicates in the file, the first record should go to valid file and remaining duplicate records should be moved to invalid file using a PIG script.

Below is the scenario.

```
Input:
Acc|Phone|Name
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
1234|987-654-3210|BLS

output: Two files

1. Valid rec:
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE

2. Invalid rec:
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
1234|987-654-3210|BLS
```

Invalid records are not necessarily to be in same order. It can also be like this.

```
Invalid rec:
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
1234|987-654-3210|BLS
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
```

Scenario 2:
Input:

```
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
1234|087-654-3210|BLS
1234|303-444-5555|XYZ
4567|122-555-1111|ABC
1234|134-123-0000|DEF
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
4567|069-258-0147|NNN
1234|086-654-3210|BLS
1234|033-444-5555|XYZ
4567|200-555-1111|ABC
1234|230-123-0000|DEF
9999|023-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-779-1234|QWE
4567|309-258-0147|NNN
1234|007-654-3210|BLS
```

Good Rec:

```
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
```

Can anyone please suggest some idea. I'm only able to get the first record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
1234|987-654-3210|BLS
```

**PigScript:**

```
A =LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (Acc:chararray,Phone:chararray,Name:chararray);
B = RANK A;
C = GROUP B BY Acc;
D = FOREACH C {
                sortInAsc = ORDER B BY rank_A ASC;
                top1 = LIMIT sortInAsc 1;
                GENERATE top1 AS goodRecord,SUBTRACT(B,top1) AS badRecord;
              }

--Flatten the good records
E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(goodRecord);

--Get the required columns and skip the rank column(ie,$0)
F = FOREACH E GENERATE $1,$2,$3;
STORE F INTO 'goodrecord' USING PigStorage('|');


--Flatten the bad records
G = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(badRecord);

--Get the required columns and skip the rank column(ie,$0)
H = FOREACH G GENERATE $1,$2,$3;
STORE H INTO 'badrecord' USING PigStorage('|');
```

**goodrecord Output1:**

```
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
```

**badrecord Output1:**

```
1234|987-654-3210|BLS
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
```

**Scenario2 goodrecord Output:**

```
1234|333-444-5555|XYZ
4567|222-555-1111|ABC
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
```

**Scenario2 badrecord Output:**

```
1234|033-444-5555|XYZ
1234|007-654-3210|BLS
1234|230-123-0000|DEF
1234|303-444-5555|XYZ
1234|234-123-0000|DEF
1234|134-123-0000|DEF
1234|086-654-3210|BLS
1234|087-654-3210|BLS
4567|369-258-0147|NNN
4567|309-258-0147|NNN
4567|122-555-1111|ABC
4567|069-258-0147|NNN
4567|200-555-1111|ABC
8734|456-879-1234|QWE
8734|456-779-1234|QWE
9999|123-456-1890|PQR
9999|023-456-1890|PQR
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.
Subtract is not available in my PIG version. Looks like it is present in 0.12+ versions. I downloaded Subtract UDF program and added to my jar.

Comment: If there are more records, this code is not returning the first record as good record.

Comment: Naveen, can you paste your input, so that i can take a look?

Comment: Hi Sivasakthi, I added the input in my question. Scenario 2. Please check.

Comment: I got good rec output as  
1234|007-654-3210|BLS <br/>
4567|069-258-0147|NNN <br/>
8734|456-779-1234|QWE <br/>
9999|023-456-1890|PQR <br/>

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you Sivasakthi.